# ¿Prescindir de los archivos de cabecera?

Tags: c++

Estoy viendo si puedo prescindir de andar trasteando con los archivos de cabecera en proyectos C++. Probablemente hayan sido la mar de buenos para C en los años '60, pero realmente hoy es dificil justificar su existencia en C++.

Escribí un pequeño programa que consta de cuatro archivos: main.cpp, file1.hpp, file2.hpp y file3.hpp
Cada archivo de cabecera tiene una clase definida dentro y esta clase sólo consta de un método. La característica es que en estos headers está la definición de la clase, no sólo la declaración como es lo usual.

La dependencia entre headers y el main se vé en el siguiente diagrama:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y los fuentes son:

```
/*************/
/* file3.hpp */
/*************/
#pragma once

class HaceAlgo3
{
public:
// Estos atributos no se usan. Sólo están porque sí.
int iA;
float fB;

public:
  float calcula(float a, int b)
  {
    return a*b;
  }
};


/*************/
/* file2.hpp */
/*************/
#pragma once
#include "file3.hpp"

class HaceAlgo2
{
public:
  float calcula(float a, float b)
  {
    HaceAlgo3 ha;
    return ha.calcula(a,3) * b;
  }
};


/*************/
/* file1.hpp */
/*************/
#pragma once
#include "file2.hpp"

class HaceAlgo1
{
public:
  int calcula(int a, int b)
  {
    return a*b;
  }
};


/************/
/* main.cpp */
/************/
#include <iostream>
#include "file1.hpp"
#include "file3.hpp"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  float fRta;

  HaceAlgo2 ha2;
  fRta = ha2.calcula(15.0, 20.0);
  printf("%f\n", fRta);

  HaceAlgo3 ha3;
  fRta = ha3.calcula(300.0, 2);
  printf("%f\n", fRta);

  return 0;
}
```

En main.cpp, la línea #include file3.hpp es innecesaria, pero al estár, y no haber errores de redefinición y compilar correctamente, mostraría en principio que programar de esta manera no traería mayores problemas.

¿Podría haber alguna clase de error al trabajar de esta forma en proyectos de varias decenas de archivos?
Desde ya muchas gracias por cualquier respuesta al respecto.

Answer (score 2):

> pero realmente hoy es dificil justificar su existencia en C++.

Nada más lejos de la realidad. C++ es un lenguaje muy complicado de interpretar ya que prácticamente todo depende del contexto (y que conste que yo desearía poder eliminar las cabeceras).

**Ejemplo 1:**

```
namespace A
{
  namespace B
  {
    int func(int var)
    {
      return var + otraFunc();
    }
  }
}
```

¿Dónde dirías que se debe encontrar `otrafunc`?

- En A::B
- En A
- En el espacio de nombres global
- En un espacio de nombres anónimo declarado previamente

**Ejemplo 2:**

```
a b(c);
```

¿Qué es esto?

- La declaración de una función
- La declaración de una variable

> ¿Podría haber alguna clase de error al trabajar de esta forma en proyectos de varias decenas de archivos?

En lo que a ti realmente te afecta, podrías encontrarte con varios inconvenientes al usar exclusivamente cabeceras:

**Tiempo de compilación**

Durante la fase de compilación, ya sea con `cmake`, `nmake`, `[loquequieras]make`, etc. Un fichero de implementación unicamente se compila si alguna de sus dependencias (ficheros de cabecera) ha sufrido cambios.

Bajo esta premisa, si no separas entre cabecera e implementación, cualquier cambio en la implementación modificará la cabecera y, en consecuencia, cualqueir archivo que incluya tu cabecera tendrá que ser recompilado... en proyectos grandes esto puede traducirse en alguna que otra hora extra de compilación.

**Visibilidad**

En C++, a diferencia de algunos lenguajes más modernos, no existe, por el momento, el concepto de librería o proyecto. Esto implica que tampoco existe la visibilidad `internal` o similar, cuyo cometido es que un elemento sea público únicamente dentro de su librería o ensamblado.

Separando el código en cabecera e implementación es facil gestionar esta característica haciendo que únicamente los ficheros de implementación carguen las cabeceras *internas*. E incluso podrías ir más lejos y eliminar las cabeceras internas a la hora de desplegar tu solución, de tal forma que nadie tiene acceso a esas clases salvo tu propia implementación.

Gestionar esta característica sin usar, como tu dices, cabeceras, es imposible, ya que las clases acabarán siendo públicas.

**Aislamiento**

Si todo el código viaja en las cabeceras y desarrollas una aplicación, más vale que la misma no vaya a ser extensible mediante plugins... los mismos necesitarán conocer, al menos, la interfaz pública de tu aplicación.

Normalmente esta interfaz pública se reduce a una serie de cabeceras sin código alguno... pero con tu diseño esas cabeceras incorporarán también el código fuente que hay por debajo y, por extensión, el código fuente de todas las clases de las que dependa esa interfaz. Eso expone (quieras o no) tu propio trabajo a la vista de los demás y crea una interfaz de acceso confusa... se supone que las interfaces no deben contener nada de código y este no sería tu caso.

Esto sería también aplicable en el caso de que programases una DLL... junto con los binarios tendrías que incluir todo el código fuente simplemente para permitir el enlazado.

**Dependencias cruzadas**

Si no separas cabeceras de implementación olvídate de aquellas arquitecturas que impliquen, de una forma o de otra, dependencias cruzadas.

```
struct Padre
{
  std::vector<Hija*> hijas;

  ~Padre()
  { std::for_each(hijas.begin(),hijas.end(),std::default_delete<Hija>()); }
};

struct Hija
{
  Padre* padre;

  Hija(Padre* padre)
    : padre(padre)
  {
    padre->hijas.push_back(this);
  }
};
```

Comment: Gracias eferion. Voy a considerar el último caso de las dependencias cruzadas, y ver si le encuentro la vuelta. En cuanto al aislamiento, si deseo protejer el código, solo debo distribuir el ejecutable como se hace con cualquier aplicacion Java, C#, o hace tiempo ya, Pascal. Ademas, hoy con lenguajes como Python o js, que para ejecutarse necesitan acceder a los fuentes (y quedan expuestos a la vista de quien quiera verlos), pierde mucho sentido protejer el código C++ con archivos de cabecera; si deseo hacerlo, solo distribuyo un .exe y los dll necesarios.

Comment: El tema de la visibilidad, quizá se pueda encarar por el lado de los espacios con nombre. No me tocó esa situación, pero creo que quizás por ese lado se pueda hacer algo correcto, entendible y elegante.  En cuanto a los tiempos de compilación, estos pueden ser una cuestión importante en (muy) grandes proyectos. Pero también es cierto que tratándose de C++, la escritura, los bugs, uso de bibliotecas y seguimiento de código, se llevan la gran parte del tiempo de desarrollo (horas, días, ...) y al final la compilación puede no pesar tanto en la ecuación.

Comment: @msx68k Los espacios de nombres tienen visibilidad pública y eso no puedes cambiarlo... de la misma forma que el contenido de una cabecera es público **siempre** (la unica excepción son los miembros `private` de las clases).

Comment: Hola eferion, es verdad que los espacios de nombre pueden ser accedidos facilmente, pero me estaba refiriendo (me olvidé de aclararlo) puntualmente a los espacios de nombre sin nombre (!) que permiten que todo lo que abarcan solo pueda ser accedido dentro del archivo en el cual están definidos. Así, esa parte del código quedaría inaccesible desde el resto del los archivos.

Comment: Y con las referencias cruzadas tuve problemas y casi me decidí por escribir un .cpp sólo para ese .hpp y así verme obligado a violar la regla JOC (Just One Cpp) !!  Pero la solución resultó ser simple, entendible y dentro del estandard JOC. Sólo se pone, a modo de referencia adelantada,  **struct Hija;** antes de las definiciones de las estructuras. Increíble lo fácil que resultó finalmente para el tiempo que le etuve dando vueltas.  Todo esto realmente me anima a pasar por completo un proyecto al estandar JOC. Sólo espero que el C++14, las QT5 y el mingw sean compatibles con ese estandard :)

Comment: @msx68k lo que comentas de los espacios de nombre, es una solución que se puede antojar incompleta rápidamente... basta con que ese código tenga que ser accedido por varias clases pero de manera interna.  Aunque claro, si eres el unico desarrollador y pasas de DLLs es mas fácil de gestionar... pero dentro de un equipo de trabajo el asunto se puede volver mas delicado

Comment: @msx68k en cuanto a las referencias cruzadas, piensa que tener includes en medio del código no es algo precisamente legible.  Por esa regla de tres podrias tener el programa completo en un unico archivo... ya puestos podrias hacerlo así y te olvidas de gestionar proyectos y dependencias. Piensa que gente mucho mas lista que tu y que yo separa, por el momento, declaración de implementación aunque el resultado,  comparado con otros lenguajes, sea horrible... por algo será

Comment: @msx68k además será que me acabo de levantar... pero no termino de ver lo que dices de las declaraciones adelantadas... en ese caso habrá un uso que no tendrá acceso a la implementación de la otra clase y entonces no compilara... lo pensaré cuando esté un poco mas despierto

Answer (score 2):

Los archivos de cabecera de C++ no se compilan, sólo se copia-pegan en los archivos de código para finalmente enlazar todos los símbolos con el enlazador. Muchas de las personas con experiencia en C++ hemos vivido y sufrido los problemas de los archivos de cabecera: como su tendencia a alargar los tiempos de compilación, a inflar el tamaño del código y a complicar la estructura de cualquier proyecto.

Por ese y otros motivos, el [comité de estándares de C++](https://isocpp.org/std/the-committee) lleva años trabajando en un sistema para acabar con los archivos de cabecera y ofrecer una alternativa moderna, más práctica y menos costosa a nivel de proceso y uso: [los módulos](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/n4720.pdf).

Hasta que lleguen los módulos, es posible prescindir de los archivos de cabecera renunciando a las plantillas (`template`), usando`extern` de manera imaginativa y con gran celo y cuidado sobre las definiciones de símbolos. Pero aunque sea posible hacerlo, el trabajo resultante es tan tedioso y complicado que es posible que acabes recorriendo tu oficina armado con un hacha y atacando a todos/as tus compañeros/as, lo último que se vería en tu escritorio sería un código fuente con este texto repetido miles de veces:

> ```
> /* Mucho trabajo y poca diversión hacen de msx68k un tipo aburrido */
> ```

Así que ¿Quieres prescindir de los archivos de cabecera en C++?: mi consejo es que no lo hagas, pese a sus conocidos problemas son la mejor herramienta que (hasta ahora) tenemos y en realidad ayudan (y mucho) a simplificar y estructurar el código fuente.

---

> En `main.cpp`, la línea `#include file3.hpp` es innecesaria, pero al estar, y no haber errores de redefinición y compilar correctamente, mostraría en principio que programar de esta manera no traería mayores problemas.

Esto es así porque el `#pragma once` que evita la doble inclusión de `file3.hpp`, de no haber usado esa extensión de MSVC deberías haber creado una [guarda de inclusión](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard), que por cierto es lo que te aconsejo usar pues el `#pragma once` no es portable.

Aún siendo innecesaria la línea `#include file3.hpp` mi consejo es mantenerla; el motivo es que las inclusiones dan información adicional al código informando al lector de las necesidades del código posterior; sólo una persona familiarizada con `file2.hpp` sabría que esa cabecera incluye `file3.hpp` pero no puedes asegurar de antemano que otros programadores conozcan `file2.hpp` (y por ello sepan que pueden prescindir de `file3.hpp`), manteniendo la inclusión de `file3.hpp` informas de manera clara y precisa de las dependencias de tu código (evidentemente se puede hacer mal y resultar más confuso, pero partamos de la premisa de que los/as compañeros/as trabajan bien).

> ¿Podría haber alguna clase de error al trabajar de esta forma en proyectos de varias decenas de archivos?

Ningún error. A lo sumo los tiempos de compilación crecerán si tus cabeceras son **muy** grandes y numerosas pero no encontrarás errores si tus guardas de inclusión son correctas.

Comment: Gracias Paula. Realmente no quiero prescindir de los archivos de cabecera, sino que quiero en ellos incluir el código de los .cpp. O sea, serían archivos .hpp con la implementación del las clases, además de las declaraciones de variables. En principio, sólo haría falta un .cpp:  main.cpp, el cual incuiría los .hpp necesarios. Sería lo mismo que la biblioteca STL en donde en las cabeceras se combinan declaraciones y definiciones y no existen los .cpp . Y no creo que nadie se atreva a decir que las STL están mal programadas :)

Comment: Entonces ¿quieres prescindir de los archivos `cpp` y que todo sean archivos de código como en [tag:java] y [tag:c#]?

Comment: Exacto. Todos menos uno (main.cpp) serían .hpp. Tengo un proyecto de 27 archivos hpp y sus respectivos 27 cpp, mas un hpp solo de declaración de variables y el main. Hoy trasladé el código de 3 cpp de importancia menor a sus respectivos hpp, y la compilación y ejecución transcurrieron sin problemas.

Comment: Entonces tu pregunta está mal redactada o no la he entendido.

Comment: Fijate en el código que todas las definiciones están en los .hpp y sólo está el main como único .cpp .